# What is the purpose of :before :after pseudo selector without content?

Tags: html, css

I am reading an article about border-box.

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

The author recommends the below CSS code:

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

I know that the :before and :after are used to insert content and style the inserted content.

But what is the purpose of the :before and :after without content?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

This is just a general formatting statement...it's not trying to insert content here so the `content` property isn't required.

Pseudo-elements don't fall under the univeral selector `*` for box-sizing so the property has to be specifically applied.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.ribbon {
   background-color: #5BC8F7;
}

.ribbon::before {
   content:          "Look at this orange box.";
   background-color: #FFBA10;
   border-color:     black;
   border-style:     dotted;
  padding: 2rem;
margin:2rem;
}
```

```html
<span class="ribbon">Notice where the orange box is.</span>
```

As you can see, padding and margins can be applicable to `:before` it is good technique to apply box sizing over them.